# Perl: Removing characters up to certain point.

Tags: string, perl, character

I've tried searching through questions already asked, but can't seem to find anything. I'm sure its incredibly simple to do, but I am completely new to Perl.

What I am trying to do is remove characters in an string up to a certain point. For example, I have:

Parameter1 : 0xFFFF

and what I would like to do is remove the "Parameter1:" and be left with just the "0xFFFF". If anyone can help and give a simple explanation of the operators used, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need the [substr](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/substr.html) function.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  my $string = 'Parameter1 : 0xFFFF';
  my $fragment =  substr $string, 12;
  print "  string: <$string>\n";
  print "fragment: <$fragment>\n";
```

Comment: `substr` makes sense only if you know *how many* characters you want to delete (or retain).

Comment: @Keith: But `index` combined with `substr` could be a valid choice (depending on the expected format of the string of course).

Comment: Yes, substr() can use an expression for the offset. - hehe we thought about it at the same time I guess!

Comment: @muistooshort: I'll weasel out of that by saying that you still need to know how many characters; you can get away with knowing it at run-time.  But a regexp solution is more idiomatic and easier to read.  `substr` might be faster in some circumstances, but I wouldn't do that kind of micro-optimization unless I know there's going to be a significant improvement.

Comment: Both solutions are technically correct.  I suggested a function because this is obviously a beginner question.

Comment: @Keith: At least you admit to weaseling :) +1 for TIMTOWTDI, I'd probably say `substr $string, length('Parameter1 :')` or `substr $string, length('Parameter1 : ')` though. I think it is good to remind people that there's more to the Swiss Army Chainsaw than regexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/.*:\s*//;
```

or

```
$s =~ s/.*:\s*//;
```

This deletes everything up to and including the first occurrence of `:` followed by zero or more whitespace characters.  With `$s =~` it's applied to `$s`; without it, it's applied to `$_`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using something like [Config::Std](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config%3a%3aStd)?

Here is how to parse a configuration file like that by hand:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %params;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if ($line =~ m{
            ^
            (?<param> Parameter[0-9]+)
            \s*? : \s*?
            (?<value> 0x[[:xdigit:]]+)
        }x ) {
        $params{ $+{param} } = $+{value};
    }
}

use YAML;
print Dump \%params;

__DATA__
Parameter1 : 0xFFFF
Parameter3 : 0xFAFF
Parameter4 : 0xCAFE
```

With `Config::Std`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Config::Std;

my $config = do { local $/; <DATA> };

read_config \$config, my %params;

use YAML;
print Dump \%params;

__DATA__
Parameter1 : 0xFFFF
Parameter3 : 0xFAFF
Parameter4 : 0xCAFE
```

Of course, in real life, you'd pass a file name to `read_config` instead of slurping it.

Answer (score 1):

I like split for these parameter/value pairs.

```
my $str = "Parameter1 : 0xFFFF";
my ($param, $value) = split /\s*:\s*/, $str, 2;
```

Note the use of LIMIT in the split, which limits the split to two fields (in case of additional colons in the value).

Comment: As an aside, I like to be able to say in my config files `Parameter1 : 0xFFFF # See Frobnicator Manual section 42.17.64` in which case the `split` approach requires additional work.

Comment: I see that Config::Std does not allow such comments either, though. `$value =~ s/#.+//;` is rather simple.